# Disable Escape key in linux?

Tags: linux, kiosk, xmodmap

Im working with a kiosk software, and it can easly be exited with the escape key.
Theres no way to disable this behaviour, why I would want to simply disable the escape key completely.

I tried with executing:

xmodmap -e "keycode 9 ="

from .Xsession, but that does not help. (Im sure that .Xsession runs, because there is other commands in .Xsession which are run correctly).

Comment: Maybe some system setting is being applied after your `.Xsession`. For example, [here's a workaround for gnome](http://superuser.com/questions/185345/why-wont-my-xmodmap-command-run-on-startup-login).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a hack, you could use a global shortcut program like Xbindkeys, and bind the escape key to `/bin/true`, which does nothing.

Comment: This needlessly invokes a program - something like `keycode 9   = NoSymbol` would be better.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, this is how I did it.

`$ cat ~/.config/xmodmap.d/disable-esc
keycode 9   = NoSymbol
keycode 66  = Escape   ! Make CAPS lock the new Escape`

This can then be invoked on logon to take effect. There are a number of ways to do that, I place it in `~/.xinitrc`.

`$ grep 'disable-esc' ~/.xinitrc
xmodmap ~/.config/xmodmap.d/disable-esc`